# Heroku: Login system - authentication loop failure

Tags: authentication, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to login to my heroku account.

I keep getting an error message that says "There was a problem with your login". There are no details of what the problem is.

I tried changing my password through the forgot password action and I still get directed back around to the above error message.

I can't contact Heroku's support team because I can't login.

Has anyone found this problem and found a way around it - or even a way to contact Heroku?

Comment: i had the same problem and the problem was because i was writing bad my password

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem... so I have tweeted Heroku about it. But I think - like one of the answers below suggests - that it's due to my password manager. But there's probably something wacky in Heroku's login form that is blocking it.

Comment: Resetting my password worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I started getting this error very recently. I believe it's linked to a recent email that I got regarding password requirement changes:

> Heroku will start resetting user account passwords today, May 4, 2022, as mentioned in our previous notification. We recommend that you reset your user account password in advance here and follow the best practices below:
>
> - Minimum of 16 characters
> - Minimum complexity of 3 out of 4: Uppercase, Lowercase, Numeric, Symbol
> - Don't just add a letter or a 1 digit number to the existing password while changing
> - Passwords may not be duplicated across accounts

As mentioned elsewhere, resetting my password and ensuring LastPass included symbols resolved it.

Comment: This helped me, I used google chrome password suggestions instead

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, couldn't login even after resetting my password. I use the Last Pass chrome extension to fill in forms. When I entered the (same) credentials in manually I was able to login.

Comment: Same here. For me, the problem was the e-mail autocomplete.

Answer (score 8):

I reset my password and it helped.

Answer (score 3):

After a research I found that Last Pass auto generated password was not strong enough as per Heroku password reset requirement.

I solved it by opening password reset link on different browser (in my case safari). enter strong password (ex: 51lxgpf2F52PgOBAPdAM@)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on "Opera", then I went to "Chrome", and still the error, but in the end it worked on "Microsoft Edge". So try changing your browser to this one)

Comment: works for me in December 2022