# Heroku - Login not working on site with an auth loop

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I have tried a few things such as resetting my password, entering everything in manually, trying all my accounts, clearing my cookies and even trying a fresh browser. However, I sadly cannot login to heroku.com

The page either refreshes itself when I press login or (rarely) gives me an error saying there was a problem with your login. Everything is indeed correct.

Any fixes would help me a ton!

Sadly, it will not let me contact support as I have to login.

Also, [Heroku: Login system - authentication loop failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610158/heroku-login-system-authentication-loop-failure) hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Before anyone says to make a new account, yes that works but I have a bit in heroku credits so I will not.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Im having the same issue

Comment: Sadly not @Daniel.Bourne

Comment: I have sent a email to account-lockout@heroku.com and they resolved it for me. It was a bug at there end

Comment: This is the second time this issue is happening to me. Awful service.

Answer (score 0):

try `heroku login -i` then enter your credentials